# Center align ggplot title when title is placed within the plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let say I have below `ggplot`

```
set.seed(1)
x<-rnorm(20)
y<-rnorm(20)
df<-data.frame(x,y)
df
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point()+ggtitle("Scatterplot")+theme(plot.title=element_text(margin=margin(t=10,b=-20)))
```

With this I am getting below `ggplot`

[image]

While this is fine, I want to centre align the title without changing it's vertical position.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(t=10,b=-20)))
```